# Как вставить переменную в Алиас?

Tags: bash

Прописываю алиас в `.bashrc` — длинную строку, которую очень часто приходится набирать. Хотелось бы реализовать это в виде алиаса или функции. В строке все время меняется только 1 значение, можно ли как-то вставить переменную внутрь?
Для примера приведу строку покороче, смысл тот же:  `grep -ri "$test" .` 
Хотелось бы чтобы можно было менять значение переменной `test`. Возможно еще будет проблема с кавычками.

Comment: А не будет ли проще написать `bash`-скрипт с параметром?

Comment: С `alias` не факт, что получится. Проще в `.bashrc` написать однострочную функцию - работает так же как с `alias`, но проще передать аргумент, т.к. `alias` добавляет аргумент в конец, т.е. `grep -ri $test` сработает, а `grep -ri $test | что_то_еще` - нет.

Answer (score 5):

В .bashrc пишете:

```
mygrep () {
    grep -ri "$1"
}
```

использование : `cat comefile | mygrep sometext`
Проверено на себе посимвольно))

Comment: С `grep` все действительно работает как надо) Но попробовал приспособить ее к некоторым более сложным конструкциям и тут уже начались траблы) Например  `knife ssh name:$1 -a ipaddress "sudo chef-client" -x chef_user -i /home/dofri/.chef/id_rsa`

Comment: @Dofri, в чем именно заключаются траблы? Вроде не должно быть проблем... Впрочем, минуту...

Comment: @Dofri, с `ssh` тоже все работает (`myssh() { ssh $1@1.1.1.1 ls }`). Поскольку я не понимаю, что именно делает Ваша команда, не уверен, что смогу дальше помочь. Попробуйте сначала написать bash-скрипт, отладить, а потом перенести его содержимое в функцию .bashrc