# Как подставить в алиас переменную, для передачи параметра?

Tags: linux, alias, zsh

В своём **.zshrc** файле я хотел сделать алиас

```
alias a2='aria2c --select-file="$1"--input-file="$2"'
```

Но ничего не получилось. Потом я прочитал что нужно сделать [функцию](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/470707/182065)

И всё равно ничего не вышло.

Но когда я пишу напрямую, то всё работает, например:

```
aria2c --select-file=2 --torrent-file=linux.torrent
```

Подскажите как можно сделать что бы подставлять цифру в первой переменной и путь во второй переменной. Цель такова, чтобы после ввода алиаса через пробел ввести цифру и ввести путь в torrent файлу. Оболочкой пользуюсь **zsh**. Файл в домашнем каталоге **.zshrc**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Исходя из [документации](http://zsh.sourceforge.net/Intro/intro_8.html), аргументы не нужно оборачивать в двойные кавычки.
В вашем случае:

```
alias a2='aria2c --select-file=$1 --torrent-file=$2'
```